# I have a problem with Hive MultiSerde Encoding

Tags: hive, hql, amazon-emr

I have created an external table on Apache Hive 3.1.3 on AWS EMR 6.14.0, using the org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.MultiDelimitSerDe class because the file uses |^| as a delimiter.
The problem is when Hive uses Tez in the background to fetch the results of SQL query like this one

```
select distinct column_name from table_name;
```

it shows some special characters like 'é' as '?' but when I run a simple query it shows the special character as it is.

I tried to add this jar hive-contrib-3.1.3-amzn-7.jar to Hive classpath but it didn't work